# Iterate through TreeSet without repeating solutions

Tags: java

I am making combinations of 3 different values that give a requested sum, in this case the requested sum is 0.
I can't find a way to iterate through a TreeSet with 2 for loops in order to receive a set of 3 numbers without repeating that solution. The third number I would like to obtain by using the contains method of the TreeSet.
This is my code so far, it gives good solutions but it repeats them.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tree
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<>();
        int array[] = {-5, 1, -4, 6, 2, 3, 9, 5};

        int sumSearching = 0;
        int valueSearching;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            ts.add(array[i]);

        for(Integer i: ts)
        {
            for(Integer j : ts)
            {
                if(i != j)
                {
                    valueSearching = sumSearching - (i + j);
                    if(valueSearching != i && valueSearching != j)
                        if(ts.contains(valueSearching))
                            System.out.println("Solution: "
                                + i + ", " + j + ", " + valueSearching);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for j > i, removing one symmetry.

This does not exclude doubles on {i, j, valueSearching} as negative numbers are involved. So one needs to maintain all solutions.

```
    Set<Set<Integer>> solutions = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i: ts)
    {
        for (int j : ts.tailSet(i, false))
        {
            valueSearching = sumSearching - (i + j);
            if (valueSearching != i && valueSearching != j)
                if (ts.contains(valueSearching)) {
                    Set<Integer> solution = new TreeSet<>();
                    Collections.addAll(solution, i, j, valueSearching);
                    if (solutions.add(solution)) {
                        System.out.println("Solution: "
                                + i + ", " + j + ", " + valueSearching);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Also note: `i != j` for Integers should better be `i.intValue() != j.intValue()` as only in the range -128 .. 127 the object for a number is unique.

Here simply the `int` primitive type is used, which is more appropriate. Also `Set.tailSet(value, exclusive)` gives the set *after* the value. Using an Iterator probably would be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this works just as expected, had no idea that the second for could be written like that in order to start from another index.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude repeating solutions, it's enough to include only those triples which are in ascending order.

So, try changing this line:

```
if (valueSearching != i && valueSearching != j)
```

to:

```
if (i < j && j < valueSearching)
```

Comment: I checked it, and it produced this output (values are different in each solution, and no solution is repeated): 
Solution: -5, -4, 9  
Solution: -5, 2, 3  
Solution: -4, 1, 3

Answer (score 0):

Implement a reversable pair class:

```
class ReversablePair<T>
{
    private final T first;
    private final T second;

    ReversablePair(final T first, final T second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    // Some getters...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o)
    {
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (!(o instanceof ReversablePair)) return false;

        final ReversablePair that = (ReversablePair) o;

        return (this.first.equals(that.first) && this.second.equals(that.second))
            || (this.first.equals(that.second) && this.second.equals(that.first));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return first.hashCode() + second.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then maintain a set of previous solutions:

```
Set<ReversablePair<Integer>> previousSolutions = new HashSet();
```

And check the set before printing:

```
if (! previousSolutions.contains(new ReversablePair<>(i, j))
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: This sometimes doesn't guarantee 3 different values in the solution, it can produce a solution like (-3, 6, -3)